# Ruby on Rails 3 : Playing with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I am running SPREE.

I am already follow the tutorial but when I reach this line, the warning is show up. 
I am already googling it but there is no solution.

```
$ bundle exec rake spree_sample:load
[DEPRECATION WARNING] Nested I18n namespace lookup under "activerecord.attributes.order" is no longer supported
```

Help me please.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Spree and will be fixed when Rails 3.2 comes out. Please just disregard this warning.